# How to not save duplicates random numbers in the array?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to save 10 random numbers in an array and without duplicates or 0s. It is working ok but saving duplicates consecutively in the loop, for e.g. 3,29,57,59,39,39,65,46,38,77. How to fix this? Thanks legends

```
  function randModulus(uint mod) public view returns (uint) {
            return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, randNonce))) % mod;   // Generate random number, Read here how this works: https://eattheblocks.com/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-smart-contract/
        }
    
    
    function generateNumbers() external returns (uint[10] memory _generatedNumbers) {
    
    
                for (uint i=0; i<generatedNumbers.length; i++) {
                    randNonce++;
                    uint number = randModulus(81);
                    if ((generatedNumbers[i] != number) && (number != 0)) {  
                        
                        generatedNumbers[i] = randModulus(81);  
                    }
                    else {   
                        i = 0;
                    }
 
      return generatedNumbers;
        
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Std set in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69672/std-set-in-solidity)

Comment: Duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69672/std-set-in-solidity

Comment: Side note: You should do the generation on server side, not on Ethereum itself. It costs more gas for no advantage.